# How to check if the word is Japanese or English using PHP

Tags: php, unicode, multibyte

I want to have different process for English word and Japanese word in this function

```
function process_word($word) {
   if($word is english) {
     /////////
   }else if($word is japanese) {
      ////////
   }
}
```

thank you

Comment: maybe it does not have to be language... just to differentiate double byte character

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A quick solution that doesn't need the `mb_string` extension:

```
if (strlen($str) != strlen(utf8_decode($str))) {
    // $str uses multi-byte chars (isn't English)
}

else {
    // $str is ASCII (probably English)
}
```

Or a modification of the [solution provided by **@Alexander Konstantinov**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856942/how-to-check-if-the-word-is-japanese-or-english-using-php/2857760#2857760):

```
function isKanji($str) {
    return preg_match('/[\x{4E00}-\x{9FBF}]/u', $str) > 0;
}

function isHiragana($str) {
    return preg_match('/[\x{3040}-\x{309F}]/u', $str) > 0;
}

function isKatakana($str) {
    return preg_match('/[\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}]/u', $str) > 0;
}

function isJapanese($str) {
    return isKanji($str) || isHiragana($str) || isKatakana($str);
}
```

Comment: This leaves out english words which use diacritics. These are not used very often, however it's a tradeoff that should be known when making the choice :)

Comment: @Thomas.Winsnes: You mean stuff like `Hai`, `Wa`, `Ka`, `Arigatou` and so on, right?

Comment: No, I mean english words like: naïve, café, résumé, soufflé etc.

Comment: @Thomas.Winsnes: Oh, I see. I never understood if those are considered valid english words or not. Specially "café", that I've never seen / heard in either british or american english.

Comment: I always write naïve with a diæresis, and diæresis with a æ.

Comment: Characters in the 4E00-9FBF range are not necessarily Japanese kanji. This range is also used to encode Chinese and Korean usage of those characters, so this is not a reliable test for whether a text is Japanese. http://unicode.org/faq/han_cjk.html#4

Comment: @PaulLegato: Do you have any solution then? I can imagine n-gram analysis would work, but it would be so much more computationally expensive.

Comment: @AlixAxel You can check for the kana Unicode ranges, given in the isHiragana() and isKatakana() functions above. Any text with either of those is almost definitely Japanese, and almost all Japanese text that isn't extremely short will have at least a few characters in those ranges. isJapanese() above should be written as just isHiragana($str) || isKatakana($str), since isKanji() will also return true for Chinese or (some) Korean text.

Answer (score 22):

This function checks whether a word contains at least one Japanese letter (I found unicode range for Japanese letters in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_writing_system)).

```
function isJapanese($word) {
    return preg_match('/[\x{4E00}-\x{9FBF}\x{3040}-\x{309F}\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}]/u', $word);
}
```

Comment: As per the comment above, characters in 4E00-9FBF are not limited to usage in Japanese, so this is not a reliable test. http://unicode.org/faq/han_cjk.html#4

Comment: Thanks Alexander for the good code. But, what does the \x do?

Comment: @TrevorW, sequence like \x{4E00} is used to specify a UTF-8 character by its hex code. See PHP manual for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Answer (score 3):

You could try Google's Translation API that has a detection function:
http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html#detect-language

Answer (score 1):

Try with [mb_detect_encoding](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) function, if encoding is EUC-JP or UTF-8  / UTF-16 it can be japanese, otherwise english. 
The better is if you can ensure which encoding each language, as UTF encodings can be used for many languages

Answer (score 0):

English text usually consists only of ASCII characters (or better say, characters in ASCII range).

Comment: Although it's fairly easy to identify most words as being either English or Japanese, there are some characters that belong to both character sets.

For example, a string containing only numbers should return true for both English and Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the charset and check if it succeeds.

Take a look at iconv: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

If you can convert a string to ISO-8859-1 it might be english, if you can convert to iso-2022-jp it is propably japanese (I might be wrong for the exact charsets, you should google for them).