# How can make ZF2's validator validates Chinese input

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to build an online information management system, which would have some Chinese input. But, ZF2's validator can't validates Chinese. What should i do to validates Chinese input? To create a custom validator? How to create one? Thank you very much!!!

[Detail see here:](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html)

```
There are actually 3 languages which are not accepted in their own script. These languages
are korean, japanese and **chinese** because this languages are using an alphabet where a
single character is build by using multiple characters.

In the case you are using these languages, the input will only be validated by using the
english alphabet.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such validator for chinese or japanese in ZF2.

What you can do is building your own small validator class. I combined [Php check if the string has Chinese chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923319/php-check-if-the-string-has-chinese-chars) and [How to check if the word is Japanese or English using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856942/how-to-check-if-the-word-is-japanese-or-english-using-php) to build these two small validators by [extending the abstract validator](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.3/library/Zend/Validator/AbstractValidator.php) for you:

```php
namespace MyApp\Validator;

use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;

// forgive the name of this class
class IsNotOrientalLanguage extends AbstractValidator
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        $this->abstractOptions['messages'] = array();

        if (preg_match('/\p{Han}+/u', $value)) {
            $this->abstractOptions['messages'][] = 'Chinese not allowed.';
        }

        if (preg_match('/[\x{4E00}-\x{9FBF}]/u', $value)) {
            $this->abstractOptions['messages'][] = 'Kankji not allowed.';
        }

        if (preg_match('/[\x{3040}-\x{309F}]/u', $value)) {
            $this->abstractOptions['messages'][] = 'Hiragana not allowed.';
        }

        if (preg_match('/[\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}]/u', $value)) {
            $this->abstractOptions['messages'][] = 'Katakana not allowed.';
        }

        return ! $this->abstractOptions['messages'];
    }
}
```

You can now use this validator wherever you want:

```php
use Zend\InputFilter\Input;
use MyApp\Validator\IsNotOrientalLanguage;

$input = new Input('blog_post');

$input->getValidatorChain()->attach(new IsNotOrientalLanguage());
```